# How can I transfer files directly from a remote computing server to my github repository without having to first download locally to PC?

Tags: github, github-actions, data-transfer, github-for-windows

I'm trying to transfer my files directly from a remote computing server to github to localize my files and have them open-access.

Since the files are the outputs of bioinformatics pipelines that I run on a remote server, I need to upload those files (typically around 30GB per job) to github to have them open-access for publication purposes so that others can see/access them.

I have tried to do it with a simple scp command but that didn't work (to no surprise).

If anyone can suggest a way to streamline this I would appreciate the help!